# Custom MediaTypeFormatter (Serializer) for ApiController specific method

Tags: c#, serialization, asp.net-web-api, mediatypeformatter

I have `ApiController` in place and one of methods needs have custom serialization.

```
    public async Task<Session> PostSession([FromBody] Session session)
```

There is massive Session object that holds everything and consumer does not want do get more than half of it, normally I could just decorate properties with `[XmlIgnore()]` and be done, however this object is being passed internally across many APIs and removing these would break these mechanisms.

Another solution would be to just replace that object with different one like `CastratedSession` and return that. I can't do this since same endpoint is being called by existing 3rd party APIs that expect to get `Session` or they would have to rewrite their stuff (not going to happen).

I then proposed to create a different endpoint that this 3rd party could call - but architect objected and said to do the custom `MediaTypeFormatter` based on specific `content-type` value they will set in header, problem is we already are using in this same controller custom `MediaTypeFormatter`, and the way I understand out of the box one can only set them in configuration per controller

```
public static void ConfigureApis(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.Formatters.Add(new CustomJsonFormatter()); 
    config.Formatters.Add(new CustomXmlFormatter()); 
}
```

Which sorta paints me into the corner.

**How (Can) I setup a custom `MediaTypeFormatter` per method on ApiController?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured out a workaround myself

I inherited and replaced `CustomXmlFormatter()` with `EvenMoreCustomXmlFormatter()`

then in `WriteToStreamAsync` did this:

```
  public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext)
    {
        if (content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType == "text/sessionXml") // this was agreed with 3rd party
        {
            //do my serialization stuff
        }
        else
        {
            return base.WriteToStreamAsync(type, value, writeStream, content, transportContext);
        }
    }
```

hope this saves you some time.

Answer (score 0):

you could write a custom action filter, override the `OnActionExecuting` method to inspect the target action, then add the proper formatter to the configuration.

```
internal class DecisionMakingFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var actionName= actionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
        if(actionName == "Some Foo")
        {
            actionContext.RequestContext.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new CustomMediaFormatter());
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
        actionContext.RequestContext.Configuration.Formatters.Remove(new CustomMediaFormatter());
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok sorry this cannot fly for me, imagine 1st request comes in and I do the replace of Mediatypeformatter (i would have to remove and add) which is global then 2nd request comes in on a different endpoint and it starts using the replacement `myCustomMediaFormater` where it shouldn't... This is a great idea for low usage system but the one I am working on has to handle thousands of requests per second so it would blow sooner than later... I recommend keeping this answer here, as it surely might benefit others. Thanks Amit.

Comment: Could someone confirm that this actually works (test it), I will mark answer as accepted if it does.